# Proof about powersets.

Tags: combinatorics

I need to prove or disprove the following statement.

For sets $A,B$ let $\mathcal{P}(A)$ denote the powerset of $A$ then:

$$\mathcal{P}(A-B)=\mathcal{P}(A)-\mathcal{P}(B)$$

No idea how to go about tackling this one so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:** What about the empty set?

Comment: I don't get what you're getting at.

Comment: Do you know how to prove that two sets $S_1$ and $S_2$ are equal? Well I am suggesting you won't be able to do this her... ask yourself if $\emptyset\in \mathcal{P}(A-B)$ and if $\emptyset \in\mathcal{P}(a)-\mathcal{P}(B)$?

Comment: Two sets are equal if you have an element of the first set then it is in the second and vice versa.

Comment: Now ask yourself that question, in particular, with the element $\emptyset$.

Comment: Still stuck, I feel like I'm quite close but I just can't make the connection sorry.

Comment: OK --- I have five minutes: is $\emptyset\in \mathcal{P}(A-B)$?

Comment: Yes I think it is.

Comment: You think? Is $\emptyset$ a subset of $A-B$?

Comment: Yes I do think so since the empty set is a subset of all sets.

Comment: Correct! Now that implies $\emptyset\in P(A)$ and $\emptyset\in P(B)$... now have we $\emptyset\in \mathcal{P}(A)-\mathcal{P}(B)$?

Comment: So since the empty set is in both P(A) and in P(B) then P(A)-P(B) would not contain the empty set therefore the sets are not equal?

Comment: ...gotta dash..

Comment: DING DING DING. That is correct and I win the accept!

Comment: Awesome thanks very much!